# Submit a form using JavaScript Is not working

Tags: javascript, laravel, forms

Hello guys I am new to coding and I was trying to submit a form with JavaScript but I keep getting and error **panier:460 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'submit')**

**This is My form**

```
<form id="myForm" action="{{ route('submit.form') }}" method="POST">
                                @csrf
                                <div class="flex items-center mb-4">
                                    <input checked id="default-radio-1" type="radio" value="490" name="radioOption" class="w-4 h-4 mr-2 text-purple-400 bg-gray-100 border-gray-300 focus:ring-purple-500 dark:focus:ring-purple-500-600 dark:ring-offset-gray-800 focus:ring-2 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600">
                                    <label for="default-radio-1" class="ms-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300">Livraison
                                        à domicile: 490 DA</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="flex items-center mb-4">
                                    <input  id="default-radio-2" type="radio" value="315" name="radioOption" class="w-4 h-4 mr-2 text-purple-400 bg-gray-100 border-gray-300 focus:ring-purple-500 dark:focus:ring-purple-500-600 dark:ring-offset-gray-800 focus:ring-2 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600">
                                    <label for="default-radio-2" class="ms-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300">Livraison
                                        StopDesk: 315 DA</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="flex items-center">
                                    <input id="default-radio-3" type="radio" value="0" name="radioOption" class="w-4 h-4 mr-2 text-purple-400 bg-gray-100 border-gray-300 focus:ring-purple-500 dark:focus:ring-purple-500-600 dark:ring-offset-gray-800 focus:ring-2 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600">
                                    <label for="default-radio-3" class="ms-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300">Retrait
                                        en magasin</label>
                                </div>
                                <button type="button" onclick="submitForm()">submit</button>
                            </form>
```

**and this is my JS script**

```
<script>
function submitForm() {
    var selectedOption = document.querySelector('input[name="radioOption"]:checked');
    consol
    if (selectedOption !== null) {
        document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
    } else {
        alert('Please select an option');
    }
}
```

*note*:*I know this question is asked before but still same results*

**Thanks in Advance**

Comment: The word `consol` in your JS will be causing an error preventing the script from running, so your form is being submit.

Comment: I removed it but still the same error

Answer (score 0):

Basically you don't need JavaScript to give the user feedback about a form field that is required. Just use the build in validation. In this case, if one of the input elements (one of the radio button options) has the attribute `required` the form will only submit if one of the buttons is selected.

```html
<form name="myform" action="path.php" method="POST">
  <div class="flex items-center mb-4">
    <input required id="default-radio-1" type="radio" value="490" name="radioOption">
    <label for="default-radio-1">Livraison à domicile: 490 DA</label>
  </div>
  <div class="flex items-center mb-4">
    <input id="default-radio-2" type="radio" value="315" name="radioOption">
    <label for="default-radio-2">Livraison StopDesk: 315 DA</label>
  </div>
  <div class="flex items-center">
    <input id="default-radio-3" type="radio" value="0" name="radioOption">
    <label for="default-radio-3">Retrait en magasin</label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

If you would like some custom massage you can add some JavaScript like this (but don't use the submit event for that):

```js
document.forms.myform.addEventListener('invalid', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let form = e.target.form;
  form.feedback.value = 'Please select an option';
}, true);

document.forms.myform.addEventListener('change', e => {
  let form = e.target.form;
  form.feedback.value = '';
});
```

```html
<form name="myform" action="path.php" method="POST">
  <div class="flex items-center mb-4">
    <input required id="default-radio-1" type="radio" value="490" name="radioOption">
    <label for="default-radio-1">Livraison à domicile: 490 DA</label>
  </div>
  <div class="flex items-center mb-4">
    <input id="default-radio-2" type="radio" value="315" name="radioOption">
    <label for="default-radio-2">Livraison StopDesk: 315 DA</label>
  </div>
  <div class="flex items-center">
    <input id="default-radio-3" type="radio" value="0" name="radioOption">
    <label for="default-radio-3">Retrait en magasin</label>
  </div>
  <div><output name="feedback"></output></div>
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```